# CSS circle mask

Tags: css, mask, masking, css-shapes

I am looking to create a dark mask at the bottom of a circle that is contained in the main circle.

can you do this using css masks?

Please see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q1eqq36u/)

```
<div id="profile-pic-wrap">
  <div id="profile-pic">
    <div class="profile-btn-bg">
      <a href="#" class="profile-pic-btn">Change Profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Put it inside the circle with an `overflow: hidden` on the red circle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `overflow:hidden;` :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q1eqq36u/2/)**

changes to your *CSS* : added `overflow:hidden;` and `text-align:center` to `#profile-pic`

```css
#profile-pic {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 999;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 left: 33px;
 background: #FFF;
 border: 3px solid #FFF;
 border-radius: 100px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
 -moz-border-radius: 100px;
 top: 0px;
 position: relative;
    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
}
.profile-btn-bg{
 position: absolute;
 background-color: black;
 width: 100%;
 height: 30%;
 bottom: 0px;
}

a.profile-pic-btn{
 color: #fff;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="profile-pic-wrap">
  <div id="profile-pic">
    <div class="profile-btn-bg">
      <a href="#" class="profile-pic-btn">Change Profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LnaxLboh/)

Added css:

```
overflow:hidden
```

and position fixed